# PHP ungreedy doen't match anything

Tags: php, preg-match

Got site that has something like that:

`<html ... data-props="{some_json_data_with_html_entities}" ...>`

I am trying to get that `JSON` with `preg_match()` but...

When using:

`'~data-props="(.*)"~'`

I am getting all the things after that... I mean there are more things in that line that contain `""`, so it catches all of it...

But when using:

`'~data-props="(.*)"~U'`

I get nothing... empty array in result.

What is going on? How do I match it correctly?

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/hV2qA2/2

Comment: When my code is pasted it just says "Timeout" with ungreedy, and works with greedy.

Comment: Is your code similar to l'L'l one?

Comment: If your string is huge make it in 2 steps `list(, $string) = explode('data-props=', $string); list($string,) = explode('"', $string);`

Comment: It is.... has few more attributes... not only json, but simple texts in quotas too..

Comment: Ok, I can't give you my code, but found site with exactly the same problem: https://ezakupy.tesco.pl/groceries/pl-PL/categories/Cat00000333 ... live example that is not working.

Comment: How about using [negation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) without `U`: [`~data-props="([^"]+)"~`](https://www.regex101.com/r/hV2qA2/3)

Answer (score 0):

You should likely be using a `JSON` parser instead, but if you want to know why it's not working (specifically example 2), that's a mystery. You would want to match `lazy`, which the `U` modifier makes it when used without the `?` quantifier. It's not clear what your actual PHP code looks like; your second pattern should've matched according to the input string.

```
data-props="(.+?)"
```

> +? [lazy] match between one and ∞ times, as few times as possible,
>   expanding as needed.

https://www.regex101.com/r/cL9xU9/1

Here's a quick example of `preg_match` using your second pattern seemingly fine:

```
$str = '<html ... data-props="{some_json_data_with_html_entities}" ... 
       "{some__moar_json_data_with_html_entities}">';
preg_match( '~data-props="(.*)"~U', $str, $res) ;
print_r($res[1]);
```

**Result:**

```
{some_json_data_with_html_entities}
```

If it's not matching then you've obviously got more in the string that we've been given.

Comment: json parsing is fine, but first I need to get that json string... on regex101.com for example, when U switch is on, it says timeout... may it be that the string is just too big to match correctly?